# Positive definiteness of matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to prove that the matrix $M$ is positive definite. I know that $R,P$ is positive definite and symmetric but i can't figure out how to simplify this expression in order to prove $M \succ 0$. Some help would be very appreciated.

$M = A^TPB\big((B^TPB+R)^{-1}-(B^TPB+R)^{-1}B^TPB(B^TPB+R)^{-1}\big)B^TPA \quad A,P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \; B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, \; R \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}, \; \; R,P \succ0, \; \; R,P \; symmetric$

Comment: Do you mean positive **semi**-definite? Because if you pick $A = 0$, you certainly don't get a positive-definite matrix.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake it should be positive semi definite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite

$$\begin{gather}M&=(B^TPA)^T (B^TPB+R)^{-1}\left((B^TPB+R)-B^TPB\right)(B^TPB+R)^{-1}(B^TPA)\\&= 
(B^TPA)^T (B^TPB+R)^{-1}\left(R\right)(B^TPB+R)^{-1}(B^TPA)\end{gather}$$
and so on.

And of course as John Hughes commented, you need $B^TPA$ to have full rank.

Comment: $x^T(B^TPA)^T(B^TPB+R)^{-1} (R) (B^TPB+R)^{-1}(B^TPA)x$ 
$=\big((B^TPB+R)^{-1}(B^TPA)x\big)^T  (P) (B^TPB+R)^{-1}(B^TPA)x \implies v^T P v \geq 0 \\$.
Where $v = (B^TPB+R)^{-1}(B^TPA)x $. Is this simplification correct?

Comment: You've turned the middle $(R)$ into a $(P)$, but otherwise, I think, yes.

Comment: Oh yeah i see that now my bad. Thanks!